# Entity Framework and DDD

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, domain-driven-design

Here's my problem: I use EntityFramework 4.1 Model first, and I have two assembly (Domain and Store)

The domain contains all my business logic
Store manages all persistence logic to the database

So I do not want any entity framework query in my Domain. I use a repository to expose the Store. The Hic! My edmx is in the Store, so the TT that generates my business classes too. As I want my business classes in the assembly's Domain , I moved the TT into the Domain and change the namespace of code generator. I must refer my Store to know my Domain classes (logic !). But how to call my repository from my Domain without creating a circular reference ...?

Summary:

- My Store reference Domain to know the business classes.
- My Domain reference Store to know the repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a repository *interface* in your domain layer. Then the repository *implementation* is in your infrastructure layer, and uses EF. This way your infrastructure layer depends on your domain layer (via the implementation of the repository interface, and the creation/retrieval of domain entities), but the domain does not depend on the infrastructure layer.

A good explanation of this general architectural pattern is given in [Jeffrey Palermo's articles on the "onion architecture"](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).

Comment: Ok its cool, It seems to keep the road. But now How can I call my repository from my Domain now? I only know the Interface layer...

Comment: Dependency injection! If `DomainThingyManipulator` needs to access the repository, it takes an `IThingyRepository` in its constructor, and in some "composition root" you stitch together the two layers with `new DomainThingyManipulator(new ActualThingyRepository())`. It's a whole topic in and of itself though, worth learning about.

Comment: You think that Microsoft Unity container may do the job? Is very cool thank you :-) !

Comment: Unity would work great! Just remember to lean as much toward dependency injection (using constructor parameters) as you can, instead of using service location (`myContainer.Resolve<IThingyRepository>()`). Either is a big improvement though!